# Windows service implementation in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-services

I am working on a MVC3 application.  I want to call a function when the date is expired.  I would like to use the windows service for this.  Can anyone tell me steps to implement the window service in a MVC3 application?  I am also open to any other options to call a function at a certain date.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible. the application pool dies after a while. Create one MVC3 application and one Windows service.

Comment: What if you created a cycle from two actions, could that keep the application pool alive? Pretty much an async action which constantly hits the other action like a game loop.

Comment: An application pool can at any time be recycled. You can not prevent that. Don't rely on IIS when it comes to background jobs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use console application and set it with window Service or create Scheduler (crone) by task manager might be it will helpyou

and its going to more easy to us if you more describe what exact-ally you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

you can implement the WCF services as a Windows service and create a call back in your Mvc3 application layer 
take a look at this link for Creating Duplex Services

> > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx